# android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner completing with 0 tests

Tags: android, robotium

I have a robotium test that I instrument as follows:

```
adb -s 169.254.255.1:5555 shell am instrument -w
<my test project identifier>/android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner
```

Earlier today, it was working correctly, running my test cases and finishing. However, now it completes

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question was to check the following:
- class name has "Test" in it
- testing method is public, and starts with the text "test"